# Lempel Ziv Complexity Normalization

Tags: solution-verification, computer-science

I'm trying to normalize the Lempel Ziv complexity measure, but I can't get it right.

I'm following the Lempel and Ziv (1976) publication where they show a theorem which defines the upper bound of LZC defined as:

$$ C(S) < \frac{N}{(1-\varepsilon_{n})\;log_\alpha(N)} $$

where

$$ \varepsilon_{n} = 2 \frac{1 + log_\alpha\;log_\alpha(\alpha N)}{log_\alpha(N)} $$

Here $N$ is the length of the sequence in study, and $\alpha$ is the number of symbols the sequence is composed of.

I think I understand this. But let's consider the binary sequence S = "0001101001000101", which has a complexity of $C(S) = 6$. The length $N$ of this sequence is 16, and $\alpha$ is 2 since it is a binary sequence.

So according to Lempel and Ziv, the following should be true:

$$  C(S) < \frac{16}{(1-\varepsilon_{n})\;log_2(16)}   $$

and

$$ \varepsilon_{n} = 2 \frac{1 + log_2\;log_2(32)}{log_2(16)} $$

But when I resolve this, I get that the upper bound is equal to -6.0517. The value not only is lower than the complexity value, but is also negative. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should link to the paper, since they have multiple papers around the same date. Is it this one "on the complexity of binary sequences"? https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/1055501

Comment: Yes, that's precisely it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though it's not explicitly stated, regardless of the LZ application, the function
$$
\varepsilon_{n} = 2 \frac{1 + \log_2\;\log_2(2n)}{\log_2(n)} $$
which is monotone decreasing for $n\geq 1,$ does not go below $1$ until $n$ is large. So it seems the inequality $\varepsilon_n<1$ won't apply before this, yielding a negative upper bound.

I suggest checking Lempel and Ziv's other papers to see if this function is used again, and if its use is clearer, stated for large $n.$

Comment: Thanks. Your answer and a little of further investigation helped me understand the nature of this normalization method. In case anyone else is having this same problem in the future, even when using this upper bound for normalization, the problem regarding the correlation between length of sequence and complexity will not be solved until N is large enough, so if you wanted to normalize complexity values for small sequences, it will not be possible (with this method, at least). That's one of the reasons every investigation that uses this complexity measure have long sequences, like N = 2000.